# Adding prefix to url for use with PHP CURL function

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get some data from a website using PHP Curl as follows:-

```
$url_1 = "website.com"
$url_2 = "http://www.website.com"
$url_3 = "http://www." . $url_1;

$ch = curl_init($url_1);       // failure
$ch = curl_init($url_2);       // success
$ch = curl_init($url_3);       // failure
```

I have a huge list of URLS in the format of $url_1 please will you let me know how I can add the http:// prefix to the url so it can be accepted by curl_init()

Thanks

Comment: Trivial string concatenation?  Or, if your list is static, open in text editor and find-replace.

Comment: My list of urls is in a mysql database. Please explain trivial string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$ch = curl_init("http://www." . trim($url_1));`

Comment: Whitespace is a killer